# JEST error: Svg is not a styled component and cannot be referred to via component selector

Tags: typescript, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

at adding "svg" as "background-image" and "src" img attribute. During testing, this error occurred: Svg is not a styled component and cannot be referred to via component selector. See https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components for more details.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AkZq.png)

I tried to find solution on https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components and other places. Unsuccessfully. I want to disappear this error. Help me, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.